# Per page header Div with settings

Tags: magento-community, static-block

I am just starting out learning Magento which is very daunting at first.  My new employer uses it so I better learn it fast.

I need to build an extension that basically allows me to insert a Custom DIV into the header of each page.

The content of each pages DIV will be pulled from a `Static Block`

Then in the settings for `Products`, `CMS`, etc pages there will be a Tab that has settings to allow to set which `Static Block` div that page will show on it's header.

So if we have 4 different `Static Blocks` that have different content for this extension, then on the settings tab for each page/section will be a dropdown list which will list all the `Static Blocks` that it can use.  So 1 of them can be selected to be shown on that particular page.

For pages that do not have a `Static block` selected in there settings, they can then use a Default block we will set in another part of the admin panel.

This sounds very difficult to me right now and I was hoping to get some advice from experienced Magento developers to see if this sounds like a good plan on how to do this.
The DIV that is to be inserted into the pages will later on be used for an exit intent popup Modal window when a user exist the page 1 time and save a cookie and not show it again.

Am I missing anything, is there a better way to do this as far as storing per page settings  and such.  Also my boss thinks Static blocks are the best route to use, is that what you would use to hold the different possible Div's content?

Answer (score 2):

You can get 80% of this functionality without using a custom extension, simply by using the built in theme capabilities and static blocks. 
What you won't get is the conditional fall back to a default block, or the drop downs, but you'll be able to achieve the same result by editing static blocks.

**So to do it without writing an extension:**

Start by creating several static blocks with names like: `custom_div_cms`, `custom_div_product`, `custom_div_checkout`. These static blocks will hold your custom div contents.

Next create a custom theme for your site if you haven't already.
In your theme we're going to add a block that can render the custom div contents, we're going to echo out that block at the appropriate place in the html structure and then we're going to tell it which static block to render for which type of page - this is quite similar to how callouts work in the default theme.

In your theme open up the layout/page.xml file, within the `<default>` element look for the block named `root` within that add the following block:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="customdiv" as="customdiv" translate="label">
    <label>My Custom Div</label>
</block>
```

This has added the block to the layout, now we need to echo out that block in the html.
Look in your themes `template/page/1column.phtml` somewhere in this you need to add the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customdiv') ?>
```

The exact location depends on where you want the custom div to be rendered to work with your design. You'll need to make the same change to `template/page/2columns-left.phtml`, `template/page/2columns-right.phtml` and `template/page/3columns.phtml` as well - basically add the echo to any page layout that may need to show your div.

Finally we need to load in the appropriate static block content into the block we've just created.
Open up `layout/cms.xml`. Look for the `<default>` node, under that add the following:

```
   <reference name="root">
        <block type="cms/block" name="custom_div" before="-">
            <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
            -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>custom_div_cms</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

This code is saying, on pages that use the default CMS layout add the contents of the static
block called `custom_div_cms` into the beginning of the block called `custom_div`.

To add it product pages insert the same code into `layout/catalog.xml` within the `<catalog_product_view>` node and change the block_id to use your custom_div_cms, to add it to the checkout and cart pages add it to `layout/checkout.xml` within the `<default>` tag changing the block_id to custom_div_checkout.

Continue this process for any types of pages that need different types of static block custom divs.

**To add fallback to a default block**

You could extend this to check if the static block is empty and then echo out a different block in a couple of ways, the right way to do this is to create your own extension, create a new block type and in that check for any static block contents before rendering the static block or a default. It's not that hard to do but takes a while to explain!

The cheats way of doing it would be to add a quick check in the theme .phtml files that rather than echoing the block, first checks for any content:

```
<?php if( empty($this->getChildHtml('customdiv') ): ?>
    <!-- some default text or echo out a different static block -->
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customdiv') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**To add drop down menus in the admin**

If you really need to add tabs to product pages, category pages, cms pages this would be a **lot** of work and some pages (like checkout) don't have any logical area in the admin where you would add those tabs anyway.

However the simplest approach would be to use configuration values to store a block id for each type of page that needs to show it (cms, products, checkout etc). You'd then create a new menu area in System > Configuration with multiple drop downs that list the available static blocks for each type of page.